# php: Change subarrays to Parent arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array generated from some code:

```
if (($handle = fopen('/var/tmp/file.tsv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    $nn = 0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, '/t')) !== FALSE) {
        $targetData = array();                 
        foreach($targetColumns as $column)      
        $targetData[] = $data[$column]; 
        $csvarray[$nn] = $targetData;
        $nn++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

This gives me this output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => "92834029"
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => "32926154"
    )
  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => "84892302"
    )
  [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => "10499507"
    )
)
```

How do I do away with the multidimension arrays and instead make it one clean simple parent array?

```
Array
(
  [0] => 92834029
  [1] => 32926154
  [2] => 84892302
  [3] => 10499507
)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to [flatten the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array/1320156)?

Comment: change this: $targetData[] = $data[$column]; 
 $csvarray[$nn] = $targetData; to this:  $csvarray[$nn] = $data[$column];

Comment: @busypeoples's fix worked! thanks really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

In your case changing it to the following will work:

```
if (($handle = fopen('/var/tmp/file.tsv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {        
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, '/t')) !== FALSE) {              
        foreach($targetColumns as $column) {          
            $csvarray[] = $data[$column];
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Took the liberty of removing unnecessary stuff too.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it that way:

```
if (($handle = fopen('/var/tmp/file.tsv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
  $nn = 0;
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, '/t')) !== FALSE) {
    foreach($targetColumns as $column)      
    $targetData = $data[$column]; 
    $csvarray[$nn] = $targetData;
    $nn++;
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

The `$targetData` is always kind of 'nulled' by the `= array()` anyway. Or assign it directly with `$csvarray[$nn] = $data[$column];`.